# how to print "no mode" when mode is not found?

Tags: c++, mode

it calculates the mode but i want it to cout "no mode" if there is no any repetition of any number . i tried diff method but every time is gives me the 1 digit of array only while there was not suppose to only print no mode this is jus the mode calculation function i have to get data from txt file and sort it and then calculate the mode

```
//calculating mode now
int num, count;
double max, mode;

for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++){
     if (num !=*(pscores+i) ){
            num = *(pscores+i);
            count = 1;
        } else {
            count++;
        }

        if (count > max){
            max = count;
            mode = num;
        }               
}
cout<<"Mode : "<<mode<<endl;
```

Comment: please format your question so it is readable

Comment: `if(mode == 0) { /* do something bro */ }`

Comment: if (mode==0)
    {
    cout<<"No mode"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
    cout<<"Mode : "<<mode<<endl;
    }
  i did this and i got this ans again Scores : 1 2 3 4 5 6 78 8 43 
Sorted Score: 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 43 78 

Median 5
Mode : 1
Program ended with exit code: 0 but i was expecting "no mode"

Comment: Initialize max and mode. No repetition means mode is 1, done.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `mode` except when `count > max`. Your if condition will as well never work because you don't initialize `max` either. Assuming your condition for "no mode" is when `count <= max`, just put an else around that and set mode and max accordingly.

```
//calculating mode now
int num = -1, count = 0;
double max = /* whatever */, mode = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++)
{
  if (num !=*(pscores+i))
  {
    num = *(pscores+i);
    count = 1;
  }
  else
    count++;

  if (count > max)
  {
    max = count;
    mode = num;
    /* maybe you want to break here? */
  }
}
if (mode == 0.0) /* this is dangerous (mode might be 0.00000001 != 0.0) */
  cout << "Mode: " << mode << endl;
else
  cout << "Mode: no mode" << endl;
```